# Accessing array [objectId] elements via Spring Boot rest api

Tags: arrays, mongodb, spring-boot

```
private List<ObjectId> issues;
private Theme theme;
```

How can I solve this problem when using array?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, use an array.